# jQuery Accordion problem with IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, nested, accordion

I have a nested accordion. Works great in Firefox, Safari, Opera, Ie8, and even IE6. But not in IE7. I get a JavaScript error after clicking one of the main 4 links and then clicking another one of the main 4 links. Ideas?
http://gator1105.hostgator.com/~carc/projects4.php

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Bad CSS on the DIV containing the entire accordion. I had a height and overflow (hidden) set on it. Overflow wasn't the problem - height was.